# simultaneous calls handling in WCF

Tags: wcf, concurrency, simultaneous

I'm new to .net and knows very little about WCF, so bear with me if any silly questions asked. I'm wondering how WCF handles simultaneous calls in SELF-HOST scenario if my code doesn't explicitly spawn any thread. So after read a lot on the stackoverflow, I created a test app but it seems not working. Please advise. Thanks a lot.

Please note ...

1. My question is only about WCF **SELF HOSTING**, so please don't refer to any IIS related.
2. I'm using **webHttpBinding**.
3. I understand there are maxConnection and service throttling settings, but I'm only interested in **2 simultaneous calls** in my research setup. So there should be no max conn or thread pool concern.
4. My test service is **NOT** using session.

Code as below ...

```
namespace myApp
{
  [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
  public interface ITestService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="test?id={id}")]
    string Test(int id);
  }

  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, 
                   ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
  public class TestService : ITestService
  {
    private static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public string Test(int id)
    {
      if (id == 1)
      {
        done.Reset();
        done.WaitOne();
      }
      else
      {
        done.Set();
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

app.config ...

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name = "TestEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name = "myApp.TestService">
        <endpoint address = "" behaviorConfiguration="TestEndpointBehavior"
                  binding = "webHttpBinding"
                  contract = "myApp.ITestService">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/test/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode = "Off" />
  </system.web>
```

How I tested ...

Once had the application running, I opened my browser, FF in case, made one call to *http://localhost:8080/test/test?id=1* . This request put the app to suspend waiting for signal, i.e. WaitOne. Then made another call in another browser tab to *http://localhost:8080/test/test?id=2*. What's expected is that this request will set the signal and thus the server will return for both requests.

But I saw the app hang and the Test function never got entered for the 2nd request. So apparently my code doesn't support simultaneous/concurrent calls. Anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in the debugger?

Comment: WCF Services are stateless, at least they are supposed to be.  This would lead me to believe each call has a separate `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: @cadrell0 this guy `private static ManualResetEvent done` has scope of AppDomain. It is shared between threads and contexts. WCF can work both ways stateless and stateful. [Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx)

Comment: @John Saunders Yes, I have. I had the break point at the very first line in the Test function, i.e. if (id == 1), and the break point was only hit once at the first request.

Comment: @cadre110 the done object is shared between threads and contexts. It can be easily verified by changing it to a List and putting the id into the list. After a few calls, we can see the List has all ids provided from the calls.

Comment: Then something else must be wrong. I presume you pressed F5 to proceed past the breakpoint. Then something else must be keeping your service from being called the second time.

Comment: I have copied your code into a Console application and I don't get your blocking behaviour described.

Please supply your complete code sample

Comment: This should not matter but you can try making InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single and remove the static ManualResetEvent. 1 instance per ServiceHost with instance context mode = Single.  
Are you console hosted?
Do you expect a max concurrency of only 2 requests. The ServiceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls does exactly that if you set it to 2.  

Again debug output the values for the request and use something like dbgView from sysinternals to check the output values if not running in the debugger.

Comment: Try setting ServiceBehaviorAttribute.UseSynchronizationContext to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single class to setup your wcf service and discard interface. You need to add global.asax file also. After you make the second call, all of them will return "finished".

This configuration does what you want.
Create TestService.cs with :

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
             ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public class TestService
{
    private static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "test?id={id}")]
    public string Test(int id)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            done.Reset();
            done.WaitOne();
        }
        else
        {
            done.Set();
        }
        return "finished";
    }


}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
<standardEndpoints>
<webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="false"  >    </standardEndpoint>


  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Global.asax file:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("testservice", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(TestService)));
    }
}
```